# Uncaught TypeError: Object function getElementById() { [native code] } has no method 'addEventListener'

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am quite new to extJs and JavaScript. I am getting an error in my javaScript code. I created a ExtJs button and assigned a handler to it. The handler creates a ExtJs messageBox. The problem is, when the button is clicked, the messageBox is not created. When I used Chrome to debug I got this error:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Object function getElementById() { [native code] } has no method 'addEventListener'"

I have searched around but so far got nothing. Below is the code:

```
var fBtn1 = new Ext.Button({
    text: 'Forward',
    tooltip: 'Send this message to more recipients',
    handler : getBox
});


function getBox() {      
    Ext.MessageBox.confirm('hello', 'how is it');
}
```

Comment: This sounds like you (or Ext JS) is doing `document.getElementById.addEventListener(...)` without calling `getElementById`. Could you provide a jsFiddle demo?

Comment: The jsFiddle framework options does not have ExtJs 2.3.0. That's the version I'm using

Comment: You can add a custom resource at "Add Resources".